# bash loop over two files and grep part of line then remove the line before if match

Tags: bash

This is `file1`:

```
8dh4rfvj-39fj-gje3-4tgf-2948l12356vz
Pdh4rfvj-39fj-gje3-4tgf-2948l12v56vz
9dh5hyu8-3tfj-gge3-4txf-29486123s1gn
8dv3p0gv-3xfj-gjz3-4tgk-3g483123f68l
9i78i7bh-3ofj-lge3-4tlf-2o486g23hbzw
8xh7fgvz-19fj-gye3-4zgf-294831b311gb
9dw996rt-33fj-zge3-4ugf-z9486123359g
```

This is `file2`:

```
name1
the_id: 8dh4rfvj-39fj-gje3-4tgf-2948l12356vz
name3
the_id: 9i78i7bh-3ofj-lge3-4tlf-2o486g23hbzw
name9
name8
the_id: 9dh5hyu8-3tfj-gge3-4txf-29486123s1gn
name7
the_id: 8xh7fgvz-19fj-gye3-4zgf-294831b311gb
name5
the_id: 9dw996rt-33fj-zge3-4ugf-z9486123359g
name10
the_id: 8dv3p0gv-3xfj-gjz3-4tgk-3g483123f68l
name12
name20
```

The format of ids: `[0-9a-z]{8}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}`.

The format of `file2`: Each line starts with `the_id`, its previous line has its name.

The names of `name1`, `name2` do not have any fixed formats, they could consist anything, even non-English letters.

I want to loop over both files and if id in `file2` exists in `file1`, then remove the `the_id` line and its previous line from `file2`, else, remain the line containing `name`.

There are some ids in `file1` that are not in `file2`.

Expected output:

```
name9
name12
name20
```

My current failed attempt to see if I can find matching line:

```
grep -oE "[0-9a-z]{8}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}" file1 | while read -r line
do
    while read -r line2
    do
        if [[ "$line" =~ ^"$line2"$ ]]
        then
            echo "$line == $line2"
        else
            echo "$line != $line2"
        fi
    done < file2
done
```

**Update 1**

Another attempt but still not a way to delete before line:

```
while read -r line
do
    while read -r line2
    do
        if [[ "$line" =~ ^"$line2"$ ]]
        then
            echo "$line == $line2"
        else
            echo "$line != $line2"
        fi
    done < <(grep -oE "[0-9a-z]{8}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}" file1)
done < file2
```

Comment: Why bash? Why not text processors like `awk`, perl or others?

Comment: @Inian because I don't know `awk` very well, but as now I'm searching and I see only removing or remaining duplicates but not anything about previous lines

Comment: I would first collect all the IDs into an array, then loop over the (name,id) pairs in file2, and write out only those where the id is not in the array. Can be done in bash, but a language like (for me) Ruby or Perl would be more normal for this task.

Comment: _I don't know awk very well_ : So in what languages do you usually program? Perhaps such a task would be a good starting point to add a new language to your toolset. You just need to learn how to read a file line by line, and how to do string comparision. These are skills which can easily be acquired from tutorials on the Net.

Comment: IMO, the main drawback of your approach is that you read `file2`  completely again and again for each line in `file1`.

Comment: @Saeed Also another way to interpret the desired output, would be to output only those lines that don't contain a `the_id` subsequently? Is the above input always the case? or can there be a `the_id` line after `name9` containing an ID not in file 1?

Comment: The format of the ids you show is not `[0-9a-z]{3}-[0-9a-z]{8}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}` as you explain in your text and not `[0-9a-z]{8}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}` as in your `grep` command. It looks like `[0-9a-z]{8,10}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}`. Which one is correct? The examples of `file1` and `file2`, the text of your question or your `grep` command? Please do not answer in comments, edit your question and fix the typo.

Comment: @user1934428 I can do with Python, but I think using bash will be more efficient (maybe my assumption is wrong that bash is faster than python). I updated the question

Comment: @Inian no, all ids in file2 exist in file1, but there maybe some ids in file1 that are not in file2. I think that might a good solution to check lines only don't contain id.

Comment: Not 100% sure about your actual input, but you can try this awk `awk 'FNR==NR { if ($0 ~ /^the_id/ && prev != "") { f = $2; map[prev]=f } else { prev = $0; }; next }
      ($0 !~ /^the_id/ && !($0 in map))
 ' file2 file2`. Will post it as an answer if it works out for you

Comment: @Inian the order should be `file1 file2`. Please edit the comment. It seems it's showing the correct result for me with real data.

Comment: No @Saeed The awk solution posted, doesn't rely on the first file at all. It only looks to find those lines that don't contain a subsequent `the_id` lines. So `file1` is not used at all

Comment: @Inian you're right. I think it's somehow showing my expected result.

Comment: With the choice of bash and Python, I would definitely do it in Python. Most likely faster in execution and more comfortable in development, because of the data structures you have in Python. For instance, you could model the collection of ids from file1 as a `Set`.

Comment: Interesting. Someone generalized the UUID, which consists of hex digits, as in , `be855089-50eb-4cf1-bf81-2ddcc2481491`, to use more characters, while retaining the same textual shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use bash for this, and if your bash is recent enough, you could try:

```
declare -a tmp
declare -A ids=()
mapfile -t tmp < file1
for i in "${tmp[@]}"; do
  [[ "$i" =~ ^[0-9a-z]{8}(-[0-9a-z]{4}){3}-[0-9a-z]{12}$ ]] && ids["$i"]=
done
while read -r line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ ^the_id:[[:space:]]+(.*) ]]; then
    [[ -v ids["${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"] ]] && unset prev
  else
    [[ -v prev ]] && printf '%s\n' "$prev"
    prev="$line"
  fi
done < file2
[[ -v prev ]] && printf '%s\n' "$prev"
```

We first use `mapfile` to store the IDs in indexed array `tmp`. Then we convert it to associative array `ids`, keeping only the IDs matching your regex. Next we loop over `file2`, setting / un-setting the `prev` variable and printing it if it is set.

Note that this would be much better and faster in `awk` or `python` or `perl`... Example with GNU `awk` and using the same ideas as with plain bash:

```
awk 'NR==FNR && $1~/^[0-9a-z]{8}(-[0-9a-z]{4}){3}-[0-9a-z]{12}$/ {ids[$1]; next}
     $1=="the_id:" {if($2 in ids) {prev=""; next}}
     prev!="" {print prev}
     {prev=$0}
     END {if(prev!="") print prev}' file1 file2
```

As noted in comments, if all IDs in `file2` are found in `file1`, then you don't care about `file1`. All you want is delete from `file2` each `the_id:` line and the preceding line. With `awk`:

```
awk '/^the_id:[[:space:]]+[0-9a-z]{8}(-[0-9a-z]{4}){3}-[0-9a-z]{12}$/ {prev=""; next}
     prev!="" {print prev} {prev=$0} END {if(prev!="") print prev}' file2
```

Or with GNU `sed`, if your file does not contain `NUL` characters:

```
sed -Ez 's/[^\n]*\nthe_id:\s+[0-9a-z]{8}(-[0-9a-z]{4}){3}-[0-9a-z]{12}\n//g' file2
```

If we consider that any line starting with `the_id:` must be deleted we can further simplify:

```
awk '/^the_id:[[:space:]]+/ {prev=""; next}
     prev!="" {print prev} {prev=$0} END {if(prev!="") print prev}' file2

sed -Ez 's/[^\n]*\nthe_id:\s+[^\n]*\n//g' file2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explains, I may not understand your answer completely l, but do you group a part of regex with parantheses and use that with BASH_REMATCH? Why not group the whole regex for example?

Comment: The first grouping `(-[0-9a-z]{4}){3}` is just for a slightly more compact regex. The second `^the_id:[[:space:]]+(.*)` is such that `BASH_REMATCH[1]` contains the ID part only and can be used to check if it is a known one, that is, if there is a corresponding key in associative array `ids`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the final solution: it contains the list of the name which are present in that file, but I'm convinced that a small change might give you what you want, without needing while- or other loops:

```
grep -B 1 -Ff file1.txt file2.txt | grep "name"
```

Explanation of the `grep` switches:

- `-B 1` : add the line **B**efore the found one.
- `-F`   : look for fix strings (not regular expressions)
- `-f`   : look inside a file for patterns